# Translate netcdf file to tif whilst retaining pixel values

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, netcdf

[EDIT] - I have added the outputs of GDAL Info into each bit - apologies if it makes this quite a large text question.

I am trying to do various processes on a netcdf file, but at the very end of my process I would like the source pixel values to be maintained.
Clearly it would be easy enough to do;

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff mynetcdffile.nc mytiffile.tif
```

And that will work fine. The output of gdalinfo for the .nc file is;
`Size is 760, 1120
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["unknown",
        DATUM["unknown",
            SPHEROID["Spheroid",6378273,298.2801225243763]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Polar_Stereographic"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",70],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-45],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["kilometre",1000,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9036"]]]
Origin = (-3850.000000000000000,5850.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (10.000000000000000,-10.000000000000000)
Metadata:
 {Deleted}
Geolocation:
  LINE_OFFSET=0
  LINE_STEP=1
  PIXEL_OFFSET=0
  PIXEL_STEP=1
  SRS=GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9108"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
  X_BAND=1
  X_DATASET=NETCDF:"ice_type_north_aggregated_2016-10-08.nc":lon
  Y_BAND=1
  Y_DATASET=NETCDF:"ice_type_north_aggregated_2016-10-08.nc":lat
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (   -3850.000,    5850.000) (168d20'58.92"E, 30d58'50.03"N)
Lower Left  (   -3850.000,   -5350.000) ( 80d44'23.20"W, 33d55'29.86"N)
Upper Right (    3750.000,    5850.000) (102d20'20.71"E, 31d21'54.91"N)
Lower Right (    3750.000,   -5350.000) (  9d58'19.41"W, 34d20'43.34"N)
Center      (     -50.000,     250.000) (146d18'35.76"E, 87d38'48.63"N)
Band 1 Block=760x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=-1
  Metadata:
   {Deleted}
  Image Structure Metadata:
    PIXELTYPE=SIGNEDBYTE`

And the output for the tiff file is
`Size is 760, 1120
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["unnamed",
    GEOGCS["unknown",
        DATUM["unknown",
            SPHEROID["Spheroid",6378273,298.2801225243763]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Polar_Stereographic"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",70],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-45],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["kilometre",1000,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9036"]]]
Origin = (-3850.000000000000000,5850.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (10.000000000000000,-10.000000000000000)
Metadata:
 {Deleted}
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (   -3850.000,    5850.000) (168d20'58.92"E, 30d58'50.03"N)
Lower Left  (   -3850.000,   -5350.000) ( 80d44'23.20"W, 33d55'29.86"N)
Upper Right (    3750.000,    5850.000) (102d20'20.71"E, 31d21'54.91"N)
Lower Right (    3750.000,   -5350.000) (  9d58'19.41"W, 34d20'43.34"N)
Center      (     -50.000,     250.000) (146d18'35.76"E, 87d38'48.63"N)
Band 1 Block=760x10 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-1
  Metadata:
   {Deleted}
  Image Structure Metadata:
    PIXELTYPE=SIGNEDBYTE`
If I look at this dataset in QGIS, I can see that the pixelsof that data only have 1 of 5 values; 0,1,2,3 and 4.

However I also need to
a: georeference it,
b: change the image size
c: change the extents of the output image.

In order to do this I have tried;

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -t_srs epsg:4326 -te -180 -90 180 90 -ts 8192 0 mynetcdffile.nc mytiffile.tif
```

and this works beautifully - *except* that the pixel values have now been scaled / changed.

The output of gdal for this tif file is;
`Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: myfile.tif
Size is 8192, 4096
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-180.000000000000000,90.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.043945312500000,-0.043945312500000)
Metadata:
  {Deleted}
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0000000,  90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (-180.0000000, -90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 90d 0' 0.00"S)
Upper Right ( 180.0000000,  90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right ( 180.0000000, -90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 90d 0' 0.00"S)
Center      (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) (  0d 0' 0.01"E,  0d 0' 0.01"N)
Band 1 Block=8192x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-1
  Metadata:
  {Deleted}`

Now when I look at it, the values of the pixels range from 0 to 255. I am thinking that this might have to do with bit depth - but am not sure.
Can anyone point me at a gdal_warp flag that might work or workaround of sorts?

I'm not keen on using any other libraries than GDAL.

Comment: Are you sure that your parameters are correct? '-ts 8192 0' seems a bit off, given that it is usually '-ts width height'.

Comment: Yeah that's fine - if you leave either of those values as 0 it'll retain aspect ratio with the given width / height.

Comment: And what does gdalinfo give you when reviewing the file?

Comment: I have updated the questions to include this info. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: It appears that you are trying to make a polar dataset (note the 'PROJECTION["Polar_Stereographic"],' from the gdalinfo of the nc-file - the full PROJ4-string for the projection of the data is '+proj=stere +a=6378273 +b=6356889.44891 +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=70 +lon_0=-45') into a global lat-lon, without actually telling the software that. You are also trying to use a nearest-neighbor resampling while doing that conversion. All in all, that'll not go well. You need to reconsider your approach.